# namespaces for dependencies imported by html tag

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

How can I make it so that I won't be able to use raw `createCanvas`, but rather through namespace like `p5.createCanvas`, while still having the dependencies handled by the html?

`index.html`

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="src/app.js"></script>
 
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

`app.js`

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(10, 10);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    circle(10, 10, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to what you are looking for in p5.js is [instance mode](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html). By default p5.js will only globally export the `p5` constructor. If you have globally declared a `setup` function then `p5.js` will globally export all of its functions, properties, and constants. If you don't want the global namespace polluted you can use instance mode instantiation, where you declare a function that takes an object that contains all of the p5 functions, properties, and constants (see example below).

```js
function mySketch(p) {
  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(400, 400);
    p.background(100);
  };
  
  p.draw = function() {
    p.circle(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, 20);
  };
  
  p.mouseClicked = function() {
    if (window.createCanvas) {
      console.log('createCanvas is globally defined.');
    } else {
      console.log('createCanvas is NOT globally defined.');
    }
  }
}

new p5(mySketch);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
 
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but is there a way for any js library to import it using a namespace

Comment: If you are using a bundler such as webpack or browserify then you can use the npm package: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p5). However, p5.js is not an ES6 module, so you cannot import it with the ES6 import statement natively in the browser. I believe you could also use [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) to import a namespaced version of p5.js since it is distributed as an AMD compatible module definition.

Comment: okay, thank you, tbh, I'm doing a big dive into html/css/js and all the browser stuff from casual programming and it all seems a bit messy down there